# automated release process

Tags: version-control

I need to use some version system and make a automated release .

Can you suggest some preferable open source software's to use and are efficient.

And how does a automated release go..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)** can be a good start (not just for release management but for any task you want to automate).

- It does integrate well with [most VCS out there](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins#Plugins-Sourcecodemanagement).
- It has several plugins related to Release Management like:

  - [Subversion Release Manager](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Release+Manager)
  - [M2 Release Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/M2+Release+Plugin) (allowing you to perform a release build using the `maven-release-plugin` from within Hudson)

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl (Java, .NET). Also see [Continuous Integration Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).